# Eclipse Plugin error: Missing constraint: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am developing eclipse plugin. The plugin include views and editors extensions. I wrote it in Linux (ubuntnu 18) and it worked. Now I want to check that it works also in windows, however, I get the next errors:
Eclipse Plugin error:

```
Missing constraint: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.resources; bundle-version="3.14.0"
Missing constraint: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.jface.text; bundle-version="3.17.0"
Missing constraint: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.editors; bundle-version="3.14.0"
Missing constraint: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.ide; bundle-version="3.18.100"
```

[image]

When I checked the dependencies tab MANIFEST.MF I see that they marked with error. When I try to re-add them, I can't find those plugins in windows... any ideas ?

Comment: What version of Eclipse is your target platform? It needs to be at least 4.19 (Eclipse 2021-03) to get these versions of those plug-ins

Comment: @greg-449 - nice !! how did you know ?

Comment: By looking at the plugin versions in different releases - it is easy enough to see from the plugin names in the 'plugins' directory. I already have every Eclipse release ever downloaded (since this sort of question comes up frequently)

Comment: I still get java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve plug-in "org.eclipse.cdt.ui". when running the plugin...

Comment: cdt.ui sounds like part of the Eclipse C/C++ code, that isn't something core Eclipse code would want.

Comment: @greg-449 - so the only way to know if the plugin compatible to eclipse version is to download eclipse version X and see what the plugin version in it ???

Comment: There might be a list somewhere, but I don't know where. If you are developing a plug-in you need to consider what is the oldest version of Eclipse you want to support - and then use that version as your Target Platform and specify the plug-in versions from that as the minimum versions.